# Redshift cross cluster insert

Tags: amazon-redshift, federated-queries

I need to insert data into a table from one redshift cluster to another.  I have it working by injecting one of my postgres rds in the middle.

Use postgres_fdw on the rds to point to the table i want to insert on in Cluser B

Use federated queries on Cluster A to write to that table in the RDS

Is there an easier way to do this without needing the RDS in the middle?  Synchronous though, I don't want to unload to a s3 bucket with a lambda rule cause that lambda rule would run async.  When my query on Cluster A finishes I want the data to be available in the data share from Cluster B.

Comment: If you have a data share already set up, you should be able to make a table or do an insert from a read-only query. That should functionally be the same as an insert. insert into table(a, b) select a, b from datashare.table

Comment: @dfundako I want to insert a table into the cluster that's sharing the data, from the consumer cluster... I just made another data share the other way around and switched to a unioned view

Answer (score -1):

Redshift data sharing is made for this use case. See [the Redshift overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/datashare-overview.html) for more details.

Comment: Data shares are read only